# How to get make asyc get with CognitoIdentityCredentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-cognito

After declaring the `cred` object with `new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` I go ahead and use `.get` method to get the credentials and store them in `IdentityId` variable. When I run this function, the `IdentityId` variable is show to be `undefined`. It seems the
`console.log("...IdentityId:", IdentityId);` is evaluated before the credenitals are queried.

Is there a way I could use `await` to get the the credentials first and then move to the `console.log` command ?

```
async function GetCredentials(email, password, callback) {

  let response = await signIn(email, password);
  console.log("...response:", response);    

  let idToken = response.response.token.idToken;

  let logins = {};
  logins[
    "cognito-idp." + AWS_REGION + ".amazonaws.com/" + AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID
  ] = idToken;
  console.log("...logins:", logins);

  let creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    Logins: logins
  });
  console.log("...creds:", creds);

  let IdentityId;
  creds.get(function(err) {
    console.log("--------------------------")
    console.log('creds.data:', creds.data);
    IdentityId = creds.data.IdentityId;
    console.log("--------------------------")
  });

  
}
```

Comment: Could you wrap it in a Promise?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so we could up-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  creds.get(function(err) {
    console.log("--------------------------")
    console.log('creds.data:', creds.data);
    const IdentityId = creds.data.IdentityId;
    resolve(IdentityId)
    console.log("--------------------------")
  });
})
const returned = await promise
```

But I'm not sure where exactly you're using `IdentityId` because your statement

> It seems the `console.log("...IdentityId:", IdentityId);` is evaluated before the credenitals are queried.

doesn't exist in your code

Comment: Please explain how did you realize that `new Promise((resolve) => {
  creds.get(function(err) {...)` should be used here instead of offered by someone `await creds.get().promise();`?

Comment: @alphanumeric I don't actually know the API of that package, that's why I made a suggestion in the comment instead. `.promise()` would only work if it actually existed as a chainable function